# Changing Drupal theme completely

Tags: theming

I am a newbie, I am in the middle of the website which was already created using the bartik theme and I want to change the theme completely like the way Main-menu looks and adding the slideshow in the middle of the page. I really don't understand how to do it. Any suggestions? Thanks.

Comment: Suggest you get an all singing, all dancing theme like AT adaptive, Omega...

Comment: Wherever you choose to start, begin with the [Theming Guide](http://drupal.org/documentation/theme) and [How to theme in Drupal 7](http://drupal.org/node/1351116).

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend starting with the "Stark" Drupal theme.  It's the minimal theme,  easier to customize.

You are also going to need to read about some basic Drupal concepts.  Views, blocks, page templating.

Your question is far too "big" to be answered in this forum.  You will have to read the documentation at drupal.org

Answer (score 0):

The question suggest you do not know where to start with performing customizations to the appearance of your Drupal site.

It is best to use a base theme, such as Omega (ht tp://drupal.org/project/omega) , and create a sub theme. Omega Tools is a module (ht tp://drupal.org/project/omega_tools) and provides a handy feature to create a sub theme.

It is good practice to use a sub theme, it saves a lot of time and effort if things go wrong and if updates become available to your base theme.

Most problems and questions you have will be answered in the following documentation:
 - ht tp://drupal.org/documentation/theme
 - ht tp://drupal.org/node/1351116

There are many modules Slideshows, here is a comparison of them ht tp://drupal.org/node/418616 . Personally I use ht tp://drupal.org/project/views_slideshow .

I do not have enough rep here to post links so if someone could be so kind to find and replace "ht tp" with "http", thanks

Answer (score -1):

The short answer is to make changes to the CSS files of you theme. Drupal Themes are more of a developer friendly environment than a graphic design environment like Wordpress themes.

Drupal "best practices" procedure is to work with a base theme and an overriding subtheme. The Zen theme is one of the most popular ways to do that. The reason to work this way is that you can update the theme without over-writing your subtheme, and hopefully the subtheme changes would be minimal.

Probably the easiest way to install a slideshow is with the Field Slideshow module. You need to add an image field to one of your content types, upload the images, and Field Slideshow instantly makes a slideshow, which you can put on any page with the block system. Well, not quite instantly, you need to grab a slideshow jquery library, but you don't have to use the amazing but complex Views module.